# How to pause/resume celery worker from consuming new tasks without setting worker_enable_remote_control as True

Tags: celery

We are using SQS as our message broker and set `worker_enable_remote_control` as `False` since it will create lots `*pidbox` queues in the SQS and aws sqs list limit is `1000` so we disable the flag `worker_enable_remote_control`.

However, we still want to be able to control the celery workers from the worker host. There is `control.cancel_consumer` and `control.add_consumer`, but they both rely on the `worker_enable_remote_control`.

Is it possible to signal the celery master worker process to cancel/add consumer from the host where the celery worker runs?

`celery version: 4.3.0`
`kombu (4.6.3)`

Thanks.

Comment: In the end, i use `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` to control the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I followed this: https://beageek.io/linux/sigcont-and-sigstop/ and used sigstop and sigcont